# Discount rate in IRS valuation

Tags: interest-rates, swaps, discounting, irs

This might be a very basic question but I didn't find the answer in the materials I saw on Google. What is the interest rate used to compute the discounted cash flows for both the fixed and variable leg for a basic vanilla interest rate swap ? 
Thank you in advance !

Comment: The general rule is "The same rate as earned by the collateral for the swap". This is generally the OIS rate (overnight-index swap rate). Prior to 2007 it was commonly the Libor rate (and some textbooks still mention  Libor for this reason).